# How to convert csv into tabular form

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, csv

I have a csv stored into a String named *csv* in controller. I have passed this string to a javascript function.The original string(in controller) had line breaks but when I download the file it is continuous i.e; in the same line though different columns values are being displayed. I want the same formatting as earlier(in tabular kind of form). Following is my controller and page code:

```
    public class PaginationForComponent {
            public PaginationForComponent(){
            allContactList = new list<wrapper>();
            myOrder = 'desc';
            sortField='name';
            PageNumber = 1;
            alphabet = new list<string>{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','Others','All'};
            RecordsPerPageslist = 10;
            System.debug('constructor called');
            csv='';
          }
          Boolean lstNamePresent=false;
          public String objName{get;set;}
          public String fieldNames{get;set;}
          list<sObject> con = new list<sObject>();
          public String alphaSearchConct{get;set;}
          public string msg {get;set;}
          public Map<id,Boolean> m = new Map<id,boolean>(); 
          list<sObject> sortedList;
          public String myOrder{get;set;}                 // Ascending or Descending order of sorting
          public String sortField{get;set;}               // Field by which sorting should be done
          public boolean selectAll{get;set;}
          public list<String> alphabet{get;set;}
          public list<sObject> cont;
          public list<wrapper> allContactList{get;set;}
          public list<wrapper> ct = new list<wrapper>();
          public list<String> query;
          public String csv{get;set;}
        public String[] getqueryList(){
            query = fieldNames.split(',');
            for(String s:query){
              if(s=='lastname'){
                lstNamePresent=true;
              }
          }
          return query;

        }

        public void docReady(){
        con = Database.query('SELECT '+ fieldNames+' FROM '+ objName );
        System.debug('docReady con is ' + con);
        for(sObject c:(list<sObject>)stdSetController.getRecords())
              allContactList.add(new wrapper(c));
        System.debug('docReady allContactList is ' + allContactList);
      }


            public void SelectedListContacts(){         // Select contacts and save them in a map  
            for(wrapper wc:allContactList){
                m.put(wc.con.id,wc.isSelected);
                if(wc.isSelected==false){
                    selectAll=false;
                 }
            }
          }

public void submit() {
    Set<id> ids = new set<id>();
    for(id i:m.keySet()){
        if(m.get(i)==true){ 
        ids.add(i);
        }
    }
    String queryStr = 'SELECT ' + fieldNames + ' FROM ' + objName + ' WHERE id IN :ids';
    sObject[] c = Database.query(queryStr);
    String temp = '';
    for(Integer i=0;i<c.size();i++){
    for(String s: query){
       temp = String.valueOf((c[i].get(s)));
       // System.debug('before escape csv temp is ' + temp);
        if(temp!=null){
            temp = temp.escapeCsv();}
       // System.debug('temp after escapeCsv() is ' + temp);
        csv += temp;
       // System.debug('str is '+str);
        csv += ', ';
    }
    csv = csv+'\n';

  }
  System.debug('csv is >>>>>>>> '+ csv);
}
```

Component code is:

```
<apex:component controller="PaginationForComponent" allowDml="true">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        function SuccessFailure(msg) {
            if(msg == '') {
                window.top.location.reload()
            } else {
                alert(msg);
            }
        }
        function cannotFind(msg){
            if(msg!=null)
                alert(msg);
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            funAtLast();
        });
        function downloadCsv(c){
            var csv = c;
            console.log(csv);   
            var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
            hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
            hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
            hiddenElement.download = 'CsvFile.csv';
            hiddenElement.click();
        }
    </script>
    <apex:attribute name="objectName" description="The object's name" type="String" required="true" assignTo="{!objName}"/>
    <apex:attribute name="fieldName" description="Fields to be displayed" type="String" required="true" assignTo="{!fieldNames}"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="form">
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!docReady}" name="funAtLast" reRender="form,alpha,table,button"/>
       <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Process" reRender="form,alpha,table,button"/>-->
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!allContactList.size!=0}" id="page">
            <!-- For alphabetic search-->
                <div align="right" >
                        <apex:repeat value="{!alphabet}" var="alph" >
                            <apex:commandLink value="{!alph}  " action="{!alphaSearch}" oncomplete="cannotFind('{!msg}');" reRender="table,button" styleClass="bghover" style="text-decoration: none;padding: " > &ensp;
                                <style type="text/css">
                                    .bghover:hover{
                                        background-color: #b3ffff;
                                    }
                                </style>
                                <apex:param name="a" value="{!alph}" assignTo="{!alphaSearchConct}"/>
                            </apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:repeat>
                </div>
            <apex:pageBlock id="table">
                <!-- To delete selected records-->
                <apex:commandButton action="{!DelSelected}" value="Delete Selected" oncomplete="SuccessFailure('{!msg}');"/>
                <!-- Button for csv download -->
                <apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Download CSV" reRender="none" oncomplete="downloadCsv('{!csv}')"/>
                <apex:pageMessages rendered="true" id="Msg"/>
                <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!WrapperContacts}" var="contacts">
                    <!-- To Edit and Delete a record -->
                   <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                        <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action[objectName].Edit,contacts.con.id)}">
                            Edit |
                        </apex:outputLink>
                        <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action[objectName].Delete,contacts.con.id)}"> 
                            Del |
                        </apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selectAll}">  
                                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!SelectedAllContacts}" reRender="table"/>
                                </apex:inputCheckbox>  
                            </apex:facet>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!contacts.isSelected}">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!SelectedListContacts}" reRender="none" />
                        </apex:inputCheckbox> 
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!queryList}" var="fldNames">
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">
                                <apex:commandLink value="{!fldNames}" action="{!toggleSort}" reRender="table">
                                    <apex:param name="sortField" value="{!fldNames}" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                                    <apex:param name="myOrder" value="{!IF(myOrder == 'DESC', 'ASC','DESC')}" assignTo="{!myOrder}" />
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </apex:facet>
                            {!contacts.con[fldNames]}
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:PageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:outputPanel id="button"> 
                <div align = "center" >
                    <!-- To return to first page of records-->
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!first}" value="<<" title="First Page" disabled="{!!HasPrevious}" reRender="table,button"/>
                    <!-- To return to Previous page of records-->
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!previous}" value="Previous" disabled="{!!HasPrevious}" reRender="table,button"/>
                    <!-- To return to next page of records-->
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!next}" value="Next >" disabled = "{!!HasNext}" reRender="table,button"/>
                    <!-- To return to last page of records-->
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!last}" value=">>" title="Last Page" disabled="{!!HasNext}" reRender="table,button"/>
                    <!-- InputText to display current page and to navigate to any page number, At righmost side of page-->
                    <span style="float:right">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Page ">
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                         <!-- To navigate to the page--> 
                        <apex:InputText value="{!PageNumber}" maxLength="4" size="1">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!NavigateByText}"  reRender="table,button"/>
                        </apex:InputText>
                         <!-- The above action support is not working-->         
                        <apex:outputLabel value=" of {!TotalPages}">
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                    </span>
                    <!-- To display a list for number of records to be selected per page-->
                    <span style = "float:left">
                        <apex:SelectList value="{!RecordsPerPageslist}" size="1" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordsPerPageOptionList}">    
                            </apex:selectOptions>
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ChangeNumberOfRecordsPerPage}" reRender="table,button"/>
                        </apex:SelectList>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>    
        </apex:outputPanel> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

PS: I have tried to provide only relevant code here, my csv download should begin on pressing the `submit` button

Comment: Your local text editor may be looking for different line endings. Are you using an IDE or developer's editor?

Comment: I am writing my code on sublime editor and my org is developer edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [JSENCODE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) function to pass the new line character to the JavaScript function.

**JSENCODE** : *Encodes text and merge field values for use in JavaScript by inserting escape characters, such as a backslash (), before unsafe JavaScript characters, such as the apostrophe (').*

In your Apex controller, you have to add `\n` as the line break and by using  JSENCODE in VF page you will get the same formatting. You can use it like this in your code.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="CSVController" >
    <script>
    function downloadCsv(c){
        var csv = c;
        console.log(csv);   
        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
        hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = 'CsvFile.csv';
        hiddenElement.click();
    }
    </script>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Download CSV" reRender="none" oncomplete="downloadCsv('{!JSENCODE(csvStr)}')"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller

```
public class CSVController {
    public String csvStr {get;set;}
    public CSVController(){
        csvStr = 'a,b,c\nd,e,f';
    }
    public pageReference submit(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Saroj it was of lot of help. I am also encountering another problem, Although i have used `String.csv()` method but still some texts are not formatted properly. Eg: `"United Oil & Gas  UK".`This whole should be in a single column but it is appearing in 2 different columns